# Can I paint the background of my gas fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

I want to paint the background of my gas fireplace (behind the logs) a lighter color so the logs and fire will be more visible.  Do you know of a paint I can use to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  These are painted all the time.  I just used [this](http://www.brick-anew.com/firebox-paint-black.html) for a traditional wood burning fireplace.  You can search for fireplace paint but really you are looking for it to withstand the max temperature.  Since yours is gas I am guessing your max is well less than 1000 F.

Also most fireboxes are painted black so you can see the fire easier.  And because of the heat a lighter color may get burn marks in it from the heat.

Comment: +1 for black.  A lighter color will only show soot better (even natural gas produces some soot), and won't actually make the fire/logs more visible.

Comment: @Nick2253 - Exactly.  All of the designers want a pretty color to sell a house.  I have seen a lot of orange lately... Which will turn to dirty orange, then brown, then brown with soot/burn marks...  Then we will get questions on how to clean paint in firebox.